# Read liquibase change log properties from external property file with maven

Tags: liquibase

I want to read Liquibase change log properties from an external property file. I do not want to define them in the databasechangelog.xml in property tag as I want different parameters for different environments. My external property file will be chosen according to the profile I chose for the maven plugin.
E.g. CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM ${schema1}.myTable FOR ${schema2}.myTable;
I want these parameters ${schema1} and ${schema2} to picked from an property file. Is this possible

**Edit: According to @bilak comment I tried this
pom.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>${basedir}/../environments/${build.profile.id}/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/sql/db-changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**liquibase.properties:**

```
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver<br>
url=xxxxx<br>
username=xxxxxx<br>
password=xxxxxx<br>
parameter.testcolumn=test_column
```

**db config parameters are read correctly but parameter.testcolumn is not used**

mvn liquibase:update -Pprofile

Answer (score 2):

You can use file liquibase.properties (default name) and put there variables like:

`parameter.schema1=yourSchema1
parameter.schema2=yourSchema2`

**edit:**
That option doesn't work with `liquibase-maven-plugin` but there could be workaround with `maven-exec-plugin`:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>liquibase</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <classpath/>
                                <argument>liquibase.integration.commandline.Main</argument>
                                <argument>--defaultsFile=src/main/resources/database/liquibase.properties</argument>
                                <argument>updateSQL</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

if you execute then `mvn exec:exec -Pliquibase` it should replace your placeholders with parameters from `liquibase.properties`.

**edit 2019/07** [Now](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/56d138a12ddd6923aad74da9e47c2a5cfe1c1ffd) you can use property file to load properties from

Comment: The liquibase documentation says:

Parameter values are looked up in the following order:

1.Passed as a parameter to your Liquibase runner (see Ant, command_line, etc. documentation for how to pass them)
2.As a JVM system property
3.In the parameters block (<property> Tag) of the DatabaseChangeLog file itself.
It does not say anything about liquibase.properties. That file is used for parameters used by various goals

Comment: just try it, you can look [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/d6dcd487fbb56a4a381491802c341f50e74bee59/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java#L674) for implementation detail. It's not documented.

Comment: I added parameter.testcolumn=test_column in my propertyfile
used as ${testcolumn} did not work

Comment: share your config and command with which are you executing liquibase.

Comment: added the pom.xml and liquibase.properties

Comment: it seems to be not working from within maven plugin. It's not implemented [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/bce767333bd4867708a03ca5fb90df868433fb44/liquibase-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/liquibase/maven/plugins/AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java#L524). There is no option to provide properties from property file. You can only set them via `expressionVars` or `expressionVariables`.

Comment: I've edited my answer with possible workaround. Cheers